# Color palettes in video games

Tags: color, art

I’ve spent the days reading all sources I can find on the use of Color palettes in games, but there is a real lack of real world examples.
Most Color palette tools generate 4-5 colours.

I am making a game where I have environment, houses, characters, items, etc. How does one Color coordinates that? How large should my palette be and should it contain the shades/tints of each Color?

Having a hard time understanding how to use Color in games, my game is low poly but I feel like I always end up with ugly colours.

Comment: This might not be a question with a concise "correct" answer. Different artists have different ways of approaching the problem. You might find you get more comprehensive answers by searching for tutorials or developer blogs/Polycount forum threads where game artists explain the process they use, and pick one that seems like it would work for you.

Comment: Providing an example might help. Could you post an example image of what you have that's not working?

Comment: One 3D game example that comes to mind is Deus Ex: Human Revolution.  Throughout the game they very often use a particular golden yellow color on many items and the UI. Another example is Just Cause 3: they use a particular shade of red on a lot of the destructive objects in the game - in this case the color palette is also functional, and there's also a shade of blue they use a lot. Unlike designing a logo or a website the color palette of a video game is much more flexible, but the tendency of using certain colors is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no definitive answer to this.  Most modern games don't really use a color palette, per se, unless you're going with an 8-bit or 16-bit vibe.  Not to say that you shouldn't or couldn't use a palette.

As for coordination, learning a little bit about [color theory](https://99designs.com/blog/tips/the-7-step-guide-to-understanding-color-theory/) never hurts.  You can also use web tools like [Paletton](http://paletton.com/) to help coordinate color groups.

But as with anything related to art, it's all rather subjective.